# Error while creating new project in Android ADT

Tags: android, adt

This is very common error, I used to get and then generally fixing the build path for the appcom makes it work for me. But this time, I don't see any such error, I deleted and updated the path for appcom, but error persist this time. R is not getting generated. How can I debug this? I just get error message of

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java

Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException   IndentRaiser
```

After taking suggestion from the comment, This is the verbrose message :

```
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Starting full Pre Compiler.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Generating BuildConfig.java...
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Starting full Package build.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Starting full Pre Compiler.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Generating BuildConfig.java...
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Starting full Package build.
[2015-01-19 17:02:08 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:09 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:09 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2015-01-19 17:02:09 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 20.0.0
[2015-01-19 17:02:09 - test] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
```

Then the code part, There is no new line added other then what comes with after creating a new project in ADT{Selected the Blank Activity for new project}.
Please let me know if any further details needed.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse preferences, you can set the build output to be verbose, as in the screenshot below. Then in the console, at the bottom, you can see exactly where it is failing. This may point you in the right direction.

[image]